# Prove $g(x+h) = g(x) + hg'(x) + \frac{1}{2} h^2 g''(x) + o(h^2)$ from definition of limit

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I want to prove $g(x+h) = g(x) + hg'(x) + \frac{1}{2} h^2 g''(x) + o(h^2)$ from the definition of limit, where x is a 1D variable, $o(h)$ is a quantity that depends on scalar h negligible compared to h as h goes to zero i.e. a small quantity

Attempt:

Recall definition of limit

$$\lim_{h\to 0} |\frac{g(x+h) - g(x) - hg'(x)}{h}| = |\frac{o(h)}{h}|$$
which turns into a more familiar form
$$\lim_{h\to 0}  |\frac{g(x+h) - g(x)}{h}| = g'(x)$$

Conclusion 
$$g(x+h) - g(x) = hg'(x) + o(h)$$

Taking a derivative wrt $x$ in above expression ields

$$g'(x+h) - g'(x) = hg''(x)$$

Sub in definition of derivative for both LHS terms

$$g(x+h^2) - g(x+h) - g(x+h) + g(x) = h^2 g''(x) + ho(h)$$

Therefore

$$g(x+h^2) = g(x) + 2hg'(x) + h^2 g''(x) + o(h^2)$$

dividing a 2 across

$$\frac{g(x+h^2)}{2}  = \frac{g(x)}{2} + hg'(x) + \frac{1}{2} h^2g''(x) + o(h^2)$$

which is not quite...
$$g(x+h) = g(x) + hg'(x) + \frac{1}{2} h^2 g''(x) + o(h^2)$$

the desired result

Can someone show me how to prove this?

Comment: You need some assumptions on $g$.

Comment: use L'hospital's  rule. You need that $g''(x)$ exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{g(x + h) - g(x) - hg'(x)}{h^{2}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{g'(x + h) - g'(x)}{2h}\text{ (by L'Hospital's Rule)}\notag\\
&= \frac{g''(x)}{2} \text{ (by definition of }g''(x))\notag\\
\end{align}

and hence $$\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{g(x + h) - g(x) - hg'(x) - \dfrac{h^{2}}{2}g''(x)}{h^{2}} = 0\tag{1}$$ i.e. $$g(x + h) = g(x) + hg'(x) + \frac{h^{2}}{2}g''(x) + o(h^{2})$$

---

Without the use of L'Hospital's rule the proof is a bit difficult. Idea is to consider the function $$f(h) = g(x + h) - g(x) - hg'(x) - \frac{h^{2}}{2}\{g''(x) - \epsilon\}$$ for any arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$. Clearly we have $f(0) = f'(0) = 0$ and $$f'(h) = g'(x + h) - g'(x) - h\{g''(x) - \epsilon\}$$ so that $f''(0) = \epsilon > 0$. Hence $f'(h) > 0$ in some neighborhood $(0, \delta_{1})$. Clearly this implies that $f(h) > 0$ in some neighborhood $(0, \delta_{1})$. Thus for any $\epsilon > 0$ we have found a $\delta_{1} > 0$ such that $f(h) > 0$ whenever $0 < h < \delta_{1}$. In other words we have $$\dfrac{g(x + h) - g(x) - hg'(x) - \dfrac{h^{2}}{2}g''(x)}{h^{2}} > -\epsilon\tag{2}$$ Considering the function $$p(h) = g(x + h) - g(x) - hg'(x) - \frac{h^{2}}{2}\{g''(x) + \epsilon\}$$ we can find a $\delta_{2} > 0$ such that $$\dfrac{g(x + h) - g(x) - hg'(x) - \dfrac{h^{2}}{2}g''(x)}{h^{2}}  < \epsilon\tag{3}$$ whenever $0 < h < \delta_{2}$. From $(2)$ and $(3)$ it follows that $$\lim_{h \to 0^{+}}\dfrac{g(x + h) - g(x) - hg'(x) - \dfrac{h^{2}}{2}g''(x)}{h^{2}} = 0$$ Similarly we can treat $h \to 0^{-}$ and thus establish the limit equation $(1)$.

In both the proofs above we have only used the fact that $g''(x)$ exists. Also note that $x$ is a fixed point and the variable being used for limit considerations is $h$ and it would have been more suitable to state the result replacing $x$ with a variable like $a$ or $c$. The result can be generalized for $n^{\text{th}}$ order derivative also (with similar proofs as given above).

*If $f^{(n)}(a)$ exists then $$f(a + h) = f(a) + hf'(a) + \frac{h^{2}}{2!}f''(a) + \cdots + \frac{h^{n}}{n!}f^{(n)}(a) + o(h^{n})$$ as $h \to 0$.*

Some people refer to the above result by the name [**Taylor's Theorem with Peano's form of remainder**](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1809293/72031) and this version of Taylor's theorem is the one which requires the least amount of conditions on the function $f$ involved.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in the third line of your derivation, $O$ is not a function. In a more exact sense, one could argue that it depends on $x$ as well as $h$ so that your fourth line is driven invalid. To obtain your desired result, you should note that $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \left( {\frac{{g(x + h) - g(x)}}{h} - g'(x)} \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \left( {\frac{{g'(x + h)}}{1} - g'(x)} \right) = 0$$where we have used L'Hopital's rule in obtaining the R.H.S. and have assumed the continuity of $g'(x)$. In a similar fashion, we have $$\begin{array}{l}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \left( {\frac{{\frac{{g(x + h) - g(x)}}{h} - g'(x)}}{h}} \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \left( {\frac{{g(x + h) - g(x) - hg'(x)}}{{{h^2}}}} \right) = \\\mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \left( {\frac{{g'(x + h) - g'(x)}}{{2h}}} \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \left( {\frac{{g''(x + h)}}{2}} \right)\end{array}$$Also note that continuity of $g''(x)$ could be implied using $$g''(x + h) = g''(x) + O(h)$$Could you see the last step?

Comment: Note that the continuity of $g''$ is not needed. Only the existence of $g''$ at a single point $x$ is needed as shown in my answer.