# Given that the function is of class $C^2$ prove the following.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

Let $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be of class $C^2$. Show that

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{g(a+h)-2g(a) +g(a-h)}{h^2} = g''(a)$$

How should one approach such questions? There are so many things that come to mind such as mean value theorem, definition of differentiability and so on but they do not lead anywhere.

Comment: hint: l'hopital

Comment: Great! thanks :)

Comment: It is not necessary that $g$ be in $C^{2}$. Just the existence of $g''(a)$ is sufficient. Either use http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1275826/72031 or directly apply L'Hopital's Rule once (not twice).

Answer (score 2):

I see two ways to solve the problem

- **First way**

$$ \frac{g(a+h)-2g(a) +g(a-h)}{h^2}=\frac 1h \Big(\frac{g(a+h)-g(a)} h-\frac{g(a)-g(a-h)} h\Big)$$ Inside brackets, at the limit, we have $(g'(a+h)-g'(a))$

- **Second way**

Assuming that the second derivative exists, Taylor expansion $$g(a+h)=g(a)+h g'(a)+\frac{1}{2} h^2 g''(a)+\frac{1}{6} h^3 g'''(a)+O\left(h^4\right)$$ $$g(a-h)=g(a)-h g'(a)+\frac{1}{2} h^2 g''(a)-\frac{1}{6} h^3 g^{(3)}(a)+O\left(h^4\right)$$ which give $$g(a+h)-2g(a)+g(a-h)=h^2 g''(a)+O\left(h^4\right)$$